# addPositionedImage() Not responding as intended

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am trying to place an positioned image using google appscripts and when I place it the document shows two images.  But when I run code to try to find the second image its like google doesn't see it at all. Please help.

```
    function createBusPasses(busNum, date, sname, teacher, address, comments) {
      var ad = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
      var docBody = ad.getBody();
      var paragraphs = docBody.getParagraphs();
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("Image URL").getBlob();
     //THIS IS THE ONE THAT IS CAUSING THE ISSUES....You have two paragraphs when running the code.  Fix it.
     var anchor = docBody.appendParagraph("Fostertown ETC").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
     anchor.addPositionedImage(blob).setWidth(200).setHeight(100);

     docBody.appendParagraph("Magnet School").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
     docBody.appendParagraph("Special Bus Transportation Form").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");

     docBody.appendParagraph("BUS NUMBER:    " + busNum + "\t\t\t\t\tDATE:    " + date).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
     docBody.appendParagraph("NAME:    " + sname + "\t\t\t\tTEACHER:    " + teacher).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("Please transport to the following address: \n\t\t" + address ).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("Comments: " + comments ).setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING2);

     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");
     docBody.appendParagraph("");

     //Clears first paragraph on initial pass

     Logger.log(paragraphs[0].getText());
     paragraphs = docBody.getParagraphs();
     if(paragraphs[0].getText() == ""){
       paragraphs[0].removeFromParent();
     }


     Logger.log(paragraphs[0].getPositionedImage());

   }
```

[Picture of resulting Google Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ycEZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

This worked for me:

```
function createBusPasses() {
  var ad = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var docBody = ad.getBody();
  var paragraphs = docBody.getParagraphs();  
  var anchor=docBody.appendParagraph("Fostertown ETC").setHeading(DocumentApp.ParagraphHeading.HEADING1);
  var blob=DriveApp.getFileById('Image File Id').getBlob();
  anchor.addPositionedImage(blob)
  .setLeftOffset(20)
  .setTopOffset(20);

}
```